# SELECT INTO with HSQLDB

Tags: sql, database, select, hsqldb

I am trying to create a new table from the result of a select. This works fine with SQL Server:

```
SELECT * INTO newTable FROM (SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM oldTable) x;
```

Now, I want to achieve the exact same thing with HSQLDB (Version 2.2). I have tried several forms like

```
SELECT * INTO newTable FROM (SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM oldTable);
SELECT INTO newTable FROM SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM oldTable;
CREATE TABLE newTable AS SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM oldTable;
```

All these variants result in some form of syntax error. How can I create a table from a select with HSQLDB?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [manual has an example](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/databaseobjects-chapt.html#dbc_table_creation) for this:

```
CREATE TABLE t (a, b, c) AS (SELECT * FROM atable) WITH DATA
```

HSQLDB *requires* parentheses around the select (unlike all other DBMS) and it also requires the `WITH DATA` clause

Comment: Awesome! I was missing the `WITH DATA` part and just could not find any documentation how to do it. Many thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Ok I found very easier way to do this.

```
select * into t_bckp FROM t;
```

Its interesting.

Comment: Doesn't work for me: `SQL Error [42581]: unexpected token: INTO required: FROM`

Comment: check your driver version.I am using HsqlDB server-2.3.3 and driver class
org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.