# Does UCanAccess accept SELECT table.* INTO ...?

Tags: java, jdbc, ucanaccess

**My code looks like this:**

```
PreparedStatement ps = null;

sql = "SELECT tblRequestsFromDWH.* INTO tblTechnique FROM tblRequestsFromDWH WHERE tblRequestsFromDWH.finalBethesda Is Null AND tblRequestsFromDWH.smearTechnique Is Not Null";

ps = module.getSupportConnection().prepareStatement(sql);
ps.execute();
```

**However when I run this I get this exception:**

```
net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::4.0.4 unexpected token: INTO required: FROM
```

However I can run this from within MS Access just fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does UCanAccess accept SELECT table.* INTO ... ?

No. UCanAccess uses HSQLDB for processing SQL statements and HSQLDB uses a [different form](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22224564/2144390):

```sql
CREATE TABLE tblTechnique (col1, col2, ...) AS (SELECT * FROM tblRequestsFromDWH) WITH DATA;
```